# How do I get a Node.js instance using Socket.io-client to talk to another Node.js instance running Socket.io on cloudfoundry?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect 2 sperate Node.js servers using Socket.io and Socket.io-client using cloudfoundry. When I test the code with both instances running locally the socket.io-client Node.js code below works as expected. When the socket.io server is cloudfoundry a simple javascript client in a browser is able to connect and works fine. However when I try to connect using the socket.io-client Node.js to the instance running on cloudfoundry it fails in a few different ways. It either does nothing, tries to connect twice and then fails, or does connect only to disconnect immediately.

The only thing I can think of is the nginx on cloudfoundry is causing something to break. It doesn't make sense to me that a javascript client in a browser can connect and send and receive data, while basically identical  Node.js code run from the same machine as the web browser cannot connect. Any ideas or should I just move away from cloudfoundry?

```
var socketioclient = require('socket.io-client').connect('http://someapiaddress.cloudfoundry.com');

socketclient = socketioclient.socket;
socketclient.on('connect_failed', function(){
    console.log('Connection Failed');
});

socketclient.on('connecting', function(){
    console.log('connecting')
});

socketclient.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');

    socketclient.on('message', function(data){
       console.log(data)
    });
    socketclient.on('disconnect', function(){
       console.log('disconnect')
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `nginx` creates problems if you are running more than one server instance, intercepting the requests every time and sending socket.io requests to different server instances. This is why you get a number of different errors:

1. does nothing,
2. tries to connect twice and then fails, or
3. does connect only to disconnect immediately.

You have to use something called `sticky sessions` to deal this. See this [link](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/01/24/scaling-real-time-apps-on-cloud-foundry-using-node-js-and-redis/) which explains the problem and gives the solution.